# Add multiple cdroms to a vm in vsphere using ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware, vsphere

I am using Ansible to create a vm on sphere. One of the requirements of this vm is that it has two cd drives, each with a disk in it.  Looking at both the [vmware_guest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_module.html) and [vsphere_guest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vsphere_guest_module.html) modules, it looks like you can't do this in one task, but I have come across [blogs](https://medium.com/@jackprice/pushing-kickstarts-with-ansible-122b2cd9c1e) that show two cd drives being created during one task using the older vsphere_guest module. Trying this, it gives me an error.

Task:

```
  -name: create vm
    ...
    vm_hardware:
      memory_mb: 2096
      num_cpus: 2
      osid: centos64Guest
      scsi: paravirtual
      vm_cdrom:
        disk1:
          type: "iso"
          iso_path: "DATASTORE/ISO1.iso"
        disk2:
          type: "iso"
           iso_path: "DATASTORE/ISO2.iso"
```

Error:

```
fatal: [hostname -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error on {'disk2': {'type:': 'iso', iso_path': 'DATASTORE/ISO2.iso'}, 'disk1': {'type:': 'iso', iso_path': 'DATASTORE/ISO1.iso'}} definition. cdrom type needs to be specified.
```

DATASTORE is the name of my datastore that the iso's are on

this leads me to believe I can't define two disks as it seems to be looking for the cd info right under vm_cdrom:

I have also tried:

```
  -name: create vm
    ...
    vm_hardware:
      ...
      vm_cdrom:
        type: "iso"
        iso_path: "DATASTORE/ISO1.iso"
       vm_cdrom:
         type: "iso"
         iso_path: "DATASTORE/ISO2.iso"
```

But this (expectedly) gives me an error stating that two vm_cdroms have been defined and it will use the last value.

Is there another way to do mount two cd's? or am I SOL?

Answer (score 0):

Added in 2.9.
IDE is currently only supported.
You need to create a list, controller_type and map the controller_number and unit_number.

```
hardware:
        num_cpus: 2
....
cdrom:
        - controller_type: ide
          controller_number: 0
          unit_number: 0 
          iso_path: "DATASTORE/ISO1.iso"
          type: iso

        - controller_type: ide
          controller_number: 0
          unit_number: 1
          iso_path: "DATASTORE/ISO2.iso"
          type: iso
```